# Buffered and unbuffered cat(1) implementation

Tags: beginner, reinventing-the-wheel, rust

I reimplemented `cat(1)` for fun. I followed the [Open Group Base Specifications (Issue 7, 2018 edition)](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cat.html), not the GNU variant and its command line arguments.

## Buffered and `-u`nbuffered behaviour

While the specification defines the behaviour for `-u`, it doesn't define how the arguments should be concatenated when the `-u`nbuffered argument is missing. To get used to `BufRead` and `BufWriter`, I used a buffered approach that simply uses Rust's already existing methods.

I'm not entirely happy about the return code issue. I currently use `io::Result` in `main` to return the last error if it occurred, however, this also means that the last error will get reported twice. I could use [`std::process::exit`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/fn.exit.html), but that would need a wrapper around `main`.

## Argument parsing and additional dependencies

I'll admit, the argument handling part of `main` won't win a beauty contest. However, I didn't want to add `clap` or other argument handling libraries and instead focus on using `std`. The program *should* follow the [Utility Argument Syntax](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02), however, it doesn't follow guidelines 5 (e.g. `-uuuu` is not the same as `-u -u -u -u`) and 9 (`-u` does not need to be the first argument). Argument grouping is a non-goal for this toy program, however.

Also, comparing to GNU `cat`, unknown options are interpreted as files names, whereas GNU `cat` will exit with an error message. I'm not sure whether that violates the specifications, though.

## Implementation

The application is split into two parts, namely `main.rs` (mostly argument parsing) and `lib.rs` (the actual implementation). Any comments on the organisation are fine.

```
// main.rs
use std::ffi::OsString;
use std::path::Path;

use cat::{cat_buffered_single, cat_unbuffered_single};

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let mut args: Vec<OsString> = std::env::args_os().skip(1).collect();

    // Only parse arguments up to "--"
    let args_up_to = if let Some(index) = args.iter().position(|arg| arg == "--") {
        args.remove(index);
        index
    } else {
        args.len()
    };

    // Keep all arguments after "--" as-is
    let verbatim_args = args.split_off(args_up_to);

    // Check for "-u" in valid positions and remove the first one
    let cat_func = if args.iter().any(|arg| arg == "-u") {
        args = args.into_iter().filter(|x| x != "-u").collect();
        cat_unbuffered_single
    } else {
        cat_buffered_single
    };

    // Recombine arguments
    args.extend(verbatim_args);

    // Fallback to stdin behaviour
    if args.is_empty() {
        args.push("-".into());
    }

    let mut result = Ok(());

    for arg in args {
        let path = Path::new(&arg);
        match cat_func(path) {
            Ok(()) => continue,
            Err(e) => {
                eprintln!("cat: {}: {}", path.to_string_lossy(), e);
                result = Err(e);
            }
        }
    }
    result
}
```

````
// lib.rs
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{self, BufRead, BufReader, BufWriter, Read, Write};
use std::path::Path;

// Dumps all bytes from `src` into `dest`, using both buffer functionalities.
fn dump_buffered_single(src: &mut dyn BufRead, dest: &mut BufWriter<impl Write>) -> io::Result<()> {
    loop {
        let buf = src.fill_buf()?;
        if buf.is_empty() {
            break;
        }
        dest.write_all(buf)?;
        let bytes = buf.len();
        src.consume(bytes);
    }
    dest.flush()
}

/// Dumps the file given by `path` on `stdout` using buffered IO.
///
/// If `path` is `"-"`, then `stdin` is used as input instead of a file.
///
/// Example
/// ```
/// # use cat::cat_buffered_single;
/// cat_buffered_single("hello.txt".as_ref());
/// ```
pub fn cat_buffered_single(path: &Path) -> io::Result<()> {
    let stdout = io::stdout();
    let handle = stdout.lock();
    let mut writer = io::BufWriter::new(handle);

    if path == Path::new("-") {
        dump_buffered_single(&mut io::stdin().lock(), &mut writer)?;
    } else {
        let input = BufReader::new(File::open(path)?);
        let mut reader = BufReader::new(input);
        dump_buffered_single(&mut reader, &mut writer)?;
    }
    Ok(writer.flush()?)
}

// Dumps all bytes from `src` into `dest`, byte by byte.
fn dump_unbuffered_single(src: &mut dyn Read, dest: &mut dyn Write) -> io::Result<()> {
    for byte in src.bytes() {
        dest.write_all(std::slice::from_ref(&byte?))?;
    }
    Ok(())
}

/// Dumps the file given by `path` on `stdout` without buffering
///
/// If `path` is `"-"`, then `stdin` is used as input instead of a file.
///
/// Example
/// ```
/// # use cat::cat_unbuffered_single;
/// cat_unbuffered_single("hello.txt".as_ref());
/// ```
pub fn cat_unbuffered_single(path: &Path) -> io::Result<()> {
    let stdout = io::stdout();
    let mut handle = stdout.lock();

    if path == Path::new("-") {
        dump_unbuffered_single(&mut io::stdin().lock(), &mut handle)?;
    } else {
        let mut file = File::open(path)?;
        dump_unbuffered_single(&mut file, &mut handle)?;
    }
    Ok(())
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use super::*;

    fn test_dump_buffered_single(test_bytes: &[u8]) {
        let src = test_bytes;
        let mut reader = BufReader::new(src);
        let mut dest = vec![];
        {
            let mut writer = BufWriter::new(&mut dest);
            dump_buffered_single(&mut reader, &mut writer).unwrap();
        }
        assert_eq!(dest, src);
    }

    #[test]
    fn dumps_all_buffered_data() {
        test_dump_buffered_single(b"Hello, World");
    }
    #[test]
    fn dumps_no_buffered_data() {
        test_dump_buffered_single(b"");
    }

    fn test_dump_unbuffered_single(bytes: &[u8]) {
        let source = bytes;
        let mut reader = source.clone();
        let mut destination = vec![];
        dump_unbuffered_single(&mut reader, &mut destination).unwrap();
        assert_eq!(destination, source);
    }
    #[test]
    fn dumps_all_unbuffered_data() {
        test_dump_unbuffered_single(b"Hello, World");
    }
    #[test]
    fn dumps_no_unbuffered_data() {
        test_dump_unbuffered_single(b"");
    }
}
````

I've used `cargo fmt` and `cargo clippy` on the code above. By the way, I see myself as a Rust beginner, so feel free to comment any part of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I would like to point out that it has been a great
pleasure to read the code with consistent formatting, helpful
comments, and clear logic.  The following points might be subjective
and nitpicky, but they don't represent my general impression.

## Argument parsing

> The program *should* follow the [Utility Argument Syntax](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02),
> however, it doesn't follow guidelines [...] 9 (`-u` does not need
> to be the first argument).

Wouldn't requiring `-u` to come before the operands make the
implementation easier though?  I'm thinking along these lines:

```
let (buffered, operands) = match args.get(0) {
    None => {
        args.push("-".into());
        (true, &args[..])
    }
    Some(arg) if *arg == "-u" => (false, &args[1..]),
    Some(_) => (true, &args[..]),
};
```

## `BufRead` and `Write`

Instead of `&mut dyn BufRead`, it's more common to take `BufRead` by
value.  The reason is that mutable references to `BufRead`
automatically implement [`BufRead`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#impl-BufRead-3).

Instead of taking an argument of type `&mut BufWriter<impl Write>`, it
suffices to take `Write`, since the functionality of `BufWriter` can
be accessed via `Write`.

Result:

```
fn dump_buffered_single<R, W>(mut src: R, mut dest: W) -> io::Result<()>
where
    R: BufRead,
    W: Write,
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the review! Yeah, the argument parsing would be easier if I supported `-u` only at the start. However, `-u` may be used several times (e.g. `-u -u` or `-uuuu`), so it's a little bit more complicated due to guideline 5. But I'll keep that in mind for future minimal argument parsing :)